# Mongo Spark connector for windows

Tags: mongodb, pyspark

How do the following commands work in windows:

```py
pyspark --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection?readPreference=primaryPreferred" \
        --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/[MyDatabase].[MyCollection]" \
        --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.0
```

I am not able to execute these in cmd or powershell

Comment: What is the error you are encountering? share the error or screenshot?